# JavaScript: binding click handler to object instance throws undefined error

Tags: javascript, jquery

Suppose I have an object `oTodo` that has two functions:

```
let oTodo = {

    getTodoList: function() {
        alert('test');
    }

    displayPageNums: function() {
        for(let i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
             $('#next').before(`<li class="page-item">
               <button onclick="oTodo.getTodoList()" class="page-link">${i}</button>
               </li>`);
        }
    },

}
```

How can I use the `getTodoList()` function inside the `onclick` event? It throws an error saying that the function is not defined.

Any idea how can I fix this?

I also tried this which also fails:

```
<button onclick="${oTodo.getTodoList()}" class="page-link">${i}</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you're using jQuery, consider using jQuery to bind the click event to your `li` elements, rather than to use inline event binding (via `onclick`) as you currently are.

Taking this approach would give you the ability to directly access the `oTodo` object and call the corresponding `getTodoList()` function as your click event handler like this:

```js
let oTodo = {

  getTodoList: function(event) {
    
    const value = event.currentTarget.dataset.value;
  
    alert(value);
  },

  displayPageNums: function() {
    for (let i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
    
      /* Create list element wrapped with jquery */
      const li = $(`<li class="page-item" data-value="${i}">
               <button class="page-link">${i}</button>
               </li>`);
  
      /* Attach oTodo.getTodoList function as handler for click event */
      li.click(oTodo.getTodoList);

      /* Add li element before next */
      $('#next').before(li);
    }
  }
}

/* Test */
oTodo.displayPageNums();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js">
</script>

<div id="next"></div>
```

Comment: sir how can i alert the value of a href if the li was clicked

Comment: yes because i tried putting a paramenter on getTOdolist function and use that parameter to alert the variable i, however it is not working

Comment: sir only the value not the other text like some/href

Comment: the value of variable i only

Comment: sir can you try to answer this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57602562/clear-html-before-appending

Answer (score 0):

well unfortunately you are trying to combine javascript with html it is not possible with jQuery its not jsx . usage of $ requires script tag

better will be you assign the nested obj fucn to a variable as

```
const someVariable = oTodo.displayPageNums;
```

and then you can use it with onclick as

```
<button onclick="someVariable()" class="page-link"></button>
```

For ${i} you have to bind it with Jquery and inject it with the $.html() function