# Clear html before appending

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have here a function that displays page number and im using the before jquery method to append the links

```
displayPageNums: function(aPages) {
   for (let i = 1; i <= aPages; i++) {

       /* Create list element wrapped with jquery */
       const li = $(`<li class="page-item" data-value="${i}">
           <button class="page-link">${i}</button>
           </li>`);

       /* Attach oTodo.getTodoList function as handler for click event */
       li.click(oTodo.getTodoList);

       /* Add li element before next */
       //$('#next').before();
       $('#next').before(li);
      }
},
```

this is the html tags

```
<nav aria-label="Page navigation example">
     <ul class="pagination">
           <li class="page-item" id="prev"><a class="page-link" href="#">Previous</a></li>
           <li class="page-item" id="next"><a class="page-link" href="#">Next</a></li>
     </ul>
</nav>
```

and this is the ajax request to get the page number on the server side

```
getTodoList: function(event) {
     const value = event ? event.currentTarget.dataset.value : 1;
     $.ajax({
         url: '/todo/rest/getTodoList?pages=' + value,
         type: 'GET',
         dataType: 'json',
         success: function(aResult) {
                oTodo.displayPageNums(aResult.sPages);
            }
        });
    },
```

I successfully display the page but whenever i click the links it just append the links again and again example

when the link is not click

[image]

when the link is clicked

[image]

I tried to clear the html using

```
   $('#next').before();
   $('#next').before(li);
```

but how ever it is not working

Answer (score 0):

```
 $('#next').empty();//this one what worked in my case
 $("#next").html(li);
```

You can clear the html `$("#next").empty();` element then add/append

`$("#next").html(li);`.

The [`empty()`](https://api.jquery.com/empty/) method removes all child nodes and content from the selected elements.

Comment: I just get the last page using that html i tried that before

Comment: @Beginner, there is a difference between the one you have tried and the one mentioned in this answer. The one that you have tried is: `$('#next').before()`. Please check that by leaving the parenthesis of `before` empty doesn't mean that, `$('#next')` will become empty. To make it empty, you have to pass an empty string to it, like the one mentioned in this answer.

Comment: im using before function to append the li when i use the html function it clears the whole i think thats why im getting only the last page

Comment: Ok, I glad you find the solution :-)

Answer (score 0):

Just add a guard to your loop, then you don't have to modify your logic:

```
displayPageNums: function(aPages) {
  for (let i = 1; i <= aPages; i++) {
    // this if "guards" that you only add items if there's no
    // page-item OR if i is greater than the number of page-items
    // on the page
    if (!$(".page-item").length || $(".page-item").length < i) {
      /* Create list element wrapped with jquery */
      const li = $(`<li class="page-item" data-value="${i}">
           <button class="page-link">${i}</button>
           </li>`);

      /* Attach oTodo.getTodoList function as handler for click event */
      li.click(oTodo.getTodoList);

      /* Add li element before next */
      //$('#next').before();
      $('#next').before(li);
    }
  }
},
```

Comment: it only display the last page

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't test out with the exact code - maybe the conditions need a little tweaking - but I think it could work. My idea was that the function should run **either** when the there's no **page-item** **OR** when the counter is greater than the number of already displayed **page-item**s. But now I see that **next** and **prev** are both **page-item**s, so they should be taken into account when setting the conditions in the **IF** statement. Maybe put a **-2** on both sides of the **OR** condition.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this, 
Change your html code as below

```html
<nav aria-label="Page navigation example">
     <ul class="pagination" id="ulPagination"></ul>
</nav>
```

And update your displayPageNum() function as below

```js
displayPageNums: function(aPages) {
    const pageHtml =  $(' <li class="page-item" id="prev"><a class="page-link" href="#">Previous</a></li>') ;
   
   for (let i = 1; i <= aPages; i++) {

       /* Create list element wrapped with jquery */
       const li = $(`<li class="page-item" data-value="${i}">
           <button class="page-link">${i}</button>
           </li>`);

       /* Attach oTodo.getTodoList function as handler for click event */
       li.click(oTodo.getTodoList);

       pageHtml.append(li)
      }
      
      pageHtml.append($('<li class="page-item" id="next"><a class="page-link" href="#">Next</a></li>'))
      $("#ulPagination").html("");
      $("#ulPagination").html(pageHtml);
},
```

Comment: it is working howevr the page links become vertical

Comment: i think it is cause by the append function

Comment: No , Page link  vertical is not the affected due to append, By the way you can apply css to make it horizontal